# Modifying a dictionary contained in a dynamic object by string at runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I have constructed the following dynamic object:

```
public class DynamicModuleBase : DynamicObject, IModuleBase
{      
    // The inner dictionary.
    Dictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public DynamicModuleBase()
    {
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = DynamicProperties[binder.Name];

        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        DynamicProperties[binder.Name] = value;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to access my dictionary by string (ie. read existing or add values).
When I try to use typical reflection mechanism that works with non-dictionary types, it returns a null:

```
PropertyInfo info = ((dynamic)myObjectInstance).GetType().GetProperty(myPropertyNameAsString);    // Returns null
```

Why is this not working in the conventional way?
What is the right way to modify the dictionary by string?

Comment: Have you tried to specify the `BindingFlags` for the `private` member? Like: `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance`

Comment: I'm not used to dynamic objects, but I suspect that Reflection (and thus the GetProperty method) works the same way as with any other type and it recognize only non-dynamic members, while anything "virtual" is ignored.

Comment: @PeterCsala, no I have not, thanks for the tip. I am going to have a play with that. If you have an example it would be welcome.

Comment: @stackMeUp The `GetProperty` does have an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetProperty_System_String_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_) which anticipates the member name and some `BindingFlags`

Comment: @PeterCsala, it does not seem to help. When using "GetProperties()" though, the dictionary is not in there, which explains why GetProperty() is not working. I read elsewhere that having "object" values in my dictionary could be the problem, but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @PeterCsala, seems that the problem is that my dictionary is defined as a field, not a property, duh!

Comment: @stackMeUp Nice catch :D